# How to save DOM elements affected by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been lightly developing a blog that is hidden until the user clicks the navigation link, then using jquery the blog container element is switched from hidden to display: block;

Because some of the pages within the blog make the page reload, I want to know how to keep the state of the page container (the one that switched from `display:none;` to `display:block;`) as a user navigates through different pages

Comment: Try `localStorage` or `$.cookie` depending on browser

Comment: I've done this in the past with an ajax call on click/trigger which sets a session variable on/off server side, then using that to determine whether to display the element or not when you load the page.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's ajax method, send a value to a PHP script and save it as a `$_SESSION` variable.

Javascript

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: 'hidden=true;
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['hidden'])){$_SESSION['hidden'] === true}
```

Edit:

Turns out you don't care about page refreshes and such. Just save some data in a `$_SESSION` variable.

If you want to do things all client side, store the value in a cookie. Use [cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie), very easy lib for working with cookies.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
});
```